# Swing GridBagLayout - Alignment issue

Tags: java, swing, alignment, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have a JPanel with a JLabel, JTextField and another JPanel with a JLabel in it.

```
    createDomainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    //createDomainPanel.setSize(600, 300);
    gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;


    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=0;
    createDomainPanel.add(new JLabel("Enter the name of the domain"), gbc);

    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=1;        
    createDomainPanel.add(domainName, gbc);

    JPanel result = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    result.add(successMessage);
    gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=2;
    createDomainPanel.add(result);
```

The last JLabel result prints a success message after a certain operation.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        SimpleDbConnect dbc = new SimpleDbConnect();
        String name = "";
        if (e.getSource()==domainName){
            name=e.getActionCommand();
            boolean success = dbc.addDomain(name);
            if (success){
                successMessage.setText("Domain "+ name + " added successfully");
            }
        }

    }
```

However the problem is when I do get a success response, the success message instead of being at the bottom appears at the right of the first JLabel. 
I'm pretty new to Swings. Can anyone help me out?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you simply forgot to use your `gbc` in `createDomainPanel.add(result)`.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Thank you @DanGetz. That was one of the silliest mistakes I've made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to pass the constraints when adding the `result`s panel

```
createDomainPanel.add(result, gbc);
```

Comment: I just feel silly now. Can't believe I didn't see that.